# Visual studio 2010 connects all databases in Server Explorer when opening a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, server-explorer

Basicly, I think the title of the post here says it all.

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel.
EDIT: I am running Windows 7 x64.

Everytime I open a solution it tries to connect to all databases present in Server Explorer. My problem is that some of them are not always available over internet so I must wait for the timeout. Anyone as ever experienced the same problem ?

I am usign the PRO version at home and it does not do it.

I disabled every plugin into Visual Studio and now I am stuck with this problem.

Finally, even Google did not help me so this is why I am trying here.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check the connect site and see if someone else is experiencing the same problem. Mine seems to happen when I connect to TFS like this

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/585566/file-source-control-go-online-causes-the-ide-to-open-all-data-connections-in-server-explorer

If you find a bug that matches your symptoms you can look for a workaround and also confirm the bug with a vote which will increase the likelyhood that it is addressed.

Comment: I am still encountering this issue in VS 2010 SP1 (and TFS 2010 SP1) but can't figure out the steps to reproduce.  Filter pending changes by solution is turned off.  I was working with a lot of xaml and cs files, and tfs work items, and then when i tried to view the properties of a silverlight 4 project, VS 2010 started to open the databases in server explorer.  If I cancel, the "connect to sql server" window comes back.  If I enter valid credentials, then VS 2010 just hangs. :(

Answer (score 1):

here's my connect bug for a similar issue. Please upvote if you encounter this lameness.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636679/visual-studio-2010-sp1-beta-tries-to-open-db-connections-when-opening-project-properties

Comment: Thanks, but the connect bug is for SP1 beta... I'll still voted!